# Plugin code doesn't working on ajax?

Tags: ajax

I have the site http://staging.cwtest.co.uk/entertainment/celebrity and i wrote the code for ajax loadmore in the button of the page. When click the load more button the ajax load the data that's is fine but i have use the plugin code inside the ajax which doesn't work properly. I have set the php parsing yes and output set the "output". So what is solution.

And ajax response code is like this

```
<?php
$i = "{segment_4}";
?>

<section class="subsection ajax">
    <div class="row">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{segment_3}" limit="2" dynamic="off" offset="`<?php echo $i;?>`" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="categories|category_fields"}
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="post-wrap">
                {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img src="{image}"></a></div>
                {/if}
                <div class="post-content">
                    <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a>
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        {exp:word_limit total="15"}
                        {body}
                        {/exp:word_limit}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            {exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{segment_3}" limit="2" dynamic="off" offset="`<?=($i+2);?>`" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="categories|category_fields"}
            <div class="wrap-content clearfix">
                <div class="post-wrap">
                    {if {count} == 1}
                        {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                        <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img
                        src="{image}"></a></div>
                        {/if}
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3>
                            <p>{exp:word_limit total="15"}{body}{/exp:word_limit}</p>
                        </div>
                    {if:else}
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3>
                            <p>{exp:word_limit total="15"}{body}{/exp:word_limit}</p>
                        </div>
                        {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                            <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img
                    src="{image}"></a></div>
                        {/if}
                    {/if}
                </div>
            </div>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
            <!-- /Wrap content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /Cols -->
    </div>
    <!-- /Row -->
    <div class="row margin-top-20">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{segment_3}" limit="3" offset="`<?=($i+4);?>`" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="categories|category_fields"}
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="post-wrap">
                {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img
                src="{image}"></a></div>
                {/if}
                <div class="post-content">
                    <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3>
                    <p>
                        {exp:word_limit total="15"}
                        {body}
                        {/exp:word_limit}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
        <!-- /Cols -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="advertisement">
                {ad_300x250_general_top}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Cols -->
    </div>
    <!-- /Row -->
    <div class="row margin-top-20">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{segment_3}" limit="3" offset="`<?=($i+8);?>`" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="categories|category_fields"}
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="wrap-content clearfix">
                <div class="post-wrap">
                    {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                    <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img
                    src="{image}"></a></div>
                    {/if}
                    <div class="post-content">
                        <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3>
                        <p>
                            {exp:word_limit total="15"}
                            {body}
                            {/exp:word_limit}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /Wrap content -->
        </div>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </div>
    <div class="row margin-top-20">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            {exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{segment_3}" limit="4" offset="`<?=($i+11);?>`" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="categories|category_fields"}
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="post-wrap">
                    {if '{exp:surgeree:modulo numerator="{count}" denominator="2"}' == 0}
                    <div class="post-content" id="{count}">
                        <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a>
                        </h3>
                        <p>
                            {exp:word_limit total="15"}
                            {body}
                            {/exp:word_limit}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                    <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img src="{image}"></a></div>
                    {/if}
                    {if:else}
                    {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                    <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img src="{image}"></a></div>
                    {/if}
                    <div class="post-content" id="{count}">
                        <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a>
                        </h3>
                        <p>
                            {exp:word_limit total="15"}
                            {body}
                            {/exp:word_limit}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    {/if}
                </div>
            </div>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
            <!-- /Cols -->
        </div>
        <!-- /Cols 9 -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="add">
                {ad_300x100_general_top}
            </div>
            <div class="add">
                {ad_300x100_general_top}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Cols -->
    </div>
</section>
<?php exit; ?>
```

Comment: Please share your code, or an example. we will need to debug your code, the issue is not with the ajax (so a good way to test is to open the AJAX URL in a browser and study the output). It is likely you have a parse order issue within your AJAX endpoint. Also please confirm the template 'type'.

Comment: I have edit the code please check the question.

Comment: And the output will be after clicking the more button in this link below please check
http://staging.cwtest.co.uk/entertainment/celebrity

Comment: Template type webpage Allow PHP yes, PHP Parsing stage to output.

Comment: Can you clean up your question? It's annoying and hard to help you if you don't format your question decently.

Comment: Hey JChrono, I asked him to post his tempalte code, but its his first post and I can't edit it to fix the code example for some reason, any idea whats going on here? Is this post in the review queue somewhere (that I can't get too?? I think its in Suggested Edits maybe??)

Comment: Padam, we're just waiting to get your OP fixed, if you can still edit it, indent all your code with 4 spaces, this gives you proper code formatting and makes it readable! In the meantime Does this template work if you browse there directly? I guess not as you have Output based PHP within and outside channel entry tags. Also what is your ajax returning? HTML??

Answer (score 1):

Ok, forget my previous answer, let me just correct this all for you!!!!

Copy paste this into your template :

```
<?php
    $i = "{segment_4}";
?>

<section class="subsection ajax">
    <div class="row">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{segment_3}" limit="2" dynamic="off" offset="<?php echo $i ?>" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="categories|category_fields"}
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="post-wrap">
                {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img src="{image}"></a></div>
                {/if}
                <div class="post-content">
                    <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a>
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        {exp:word_limit total="15"}
                        {body}
                        {/exp:word_limit}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            {exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{segment_3}" limit="2" dynamic="off" offset="<?php echo ($i+2) ?>" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="categories|category_fields"}
            <div class="wrap-content clearfix">
                <div class="post-wrap">
                    {if {count} == 1}
                        {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                        <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img
                        src="{image}"></a></div>
                        {/if}
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3>
                            <p>{exp:word_limit total="15"}{body}{/exp:word_limit}</p>
                        </div>
                    {if:else}
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3>
                            <p>{exp:word_limit total="15"}{body}{/exp:word_limit}</p>
                        </div>
                        {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                            <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img
                    src="{image}"></a></div>
                        {/if}
                    {/if}
                </div>
            </div>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
            <!-- /Wrap content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /Cols -->
    </div>
    <!-- /Row -->
    <div class="row margin-top-20">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{segment_3}" limit="3" offset="<?php echo ($i+4) ?>" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="categories|category_fields"}
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="post-wrap">
                {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img
                src="{image}"></a></div>
                {/if}
                <div class="post-content">
                    <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3>
                    <p>
                        {exp:word_limit total="15"}
                        {body}
                        {/exp:word_limit}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
        <!-- /Cols -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="advertisement">
                {ad_300x250_general_top}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Cols -->
    </div>
    <!-- /Row -->
    <div class="row margin-top-20">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{segment_3}" limit="3" offset="<?php echo ($i+8) ?>" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="categories|category_fields"}
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="wrap-content clearfix">
                <div class="post-wrap">
                    {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                    <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img
                    src="{image}"></a></div>
                    {/if}
                    <div class="post-content">
                        <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3>
                        <p>
                            {exp:word_limit total="15"}
                            {body}
                            {/exp:word_limit}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /Wrap content -->
        </div>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </div>
    <div class="row margin-top-20">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            {exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{segment_3}" limit="4" offset="<?php echo ($i+11) ?>" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="categories|category_fields"}
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="post-wrap">
                    {if '{exp:surgeree:modulo numerator="{count}" denominator="2"}' == 0}
                    <div class="post-content" id="{count}">
                        <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a>
                        </h3>
                        <p>
                            {exp:word_limit total="15"}
                            {body}
                            {/exp:word_limit}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                    <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img src="{image}"></a></div>
                    {/if}
                    {if:else}
                    {if "{image}"!="" && '{exp:bn_file_exists:check_file src="{image}"}'}
                    <div class="post-images"><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}"><img src="{image}"></a></div>
                    {/if}
                    <div class="post-content" id="{count}">
                        <h3><a href="/{embed:category_name}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a>
                        </h3>
                        <p>
                            {exp:word_limit total="15"}
                            {body}
                            {/exp:word_limit}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    {/if}
                </div>
            </div>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
            <!-- /Cols -->
        </div>
        <!-- /Cols 9 -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="add">
                {ad_300x100_general_top}
            </div>
            <div class="add">
                {ad_300x100_general_top}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Cols -->
    </div>
</section>
```

**PHP ON INPUT**

What I did :

1. Removed the `exit`
2. Removed the angled quoates from around your php tags

Please let us know how you fair with this...

Comment: If exit is remove it is redirect to another page.

Comment: HI Padam, in that case you will need to look at the routing of your site, and find out where exactly that redirect is, because its in the template you shared. Generally I set up an AJAX route so that the template can be reached directly, not via any layout or index templates you might have. Or it could be that you arn't returning false in your Javascript and so the anchor tag is being followed?

Comment: Is it ok if we could discuss this matter in a chat ?

Comment: Sorry Padam, I am at work and quite busy so I can't chat at the moment. Sorry.

Comment: so when you are free please add my skype address padam.shankhadev1
I am in really need of some help. I am not able to move further in my project.